# Updating postgres column with sequence of integers

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, auto-populate

I have a postgres table `bar` that contains 130 rows.  I would like to auto-populate the `id` column with a sequence of incrementing integers from 1 to 130.  When I try the following code:

```
update bar
set id = t.num FROM (
SELECT  *
FROM    generate_series(1, 130) num) t
```

The column is updated but every row contains 1.  What I am doing wrong here and what is the correct syntax for this procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a primary key to identify each row.  Then you can use:

```
update bar b
   set id = b2.new_id
   from (select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) as new_id
         from bar
        ) b2;
   where b.pk = b2.pk;
```

Your version is attempting to update each row 130 times.  Only one update is kept -- seemingly the first one but you cannot depend on that.